# Mq Series access to a few topics

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I develope small application to subscribe messages from some topics. When I connect to one topic is all right and I receives messages, but when I try connect to a few topics I don't receive any messages. I connect to topics like this:

```
string topics = "TOPIC_1 | TOPIC_2 | TOPIC_3";

mqQMgr.AccessTopic(topics, topicObject, MQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_SUBSCRIPTION, openOptionsForGet);
```

How I should connect to a few topics at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak c# too well, but I don't think that type of operation/syntax is supported. You probably need to issue three separate calls to access each topic individually.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nicholas says, you'll have to subscribe to them individually. Unless of course they are similar and can subscribed using a wildcard.

For example to subscribe to these three topics:-

- Price/Fruit/Apples/Bramley
- Price/Fruit/Oranges
- Price/Fruit/Bananas

I could make one subscription to a topic "Price/Fruit/#"

If the topic strings in your question are really what you are using your could make a character scheme wildcard (`MQSO_WILDCARD_CHAR`) for "TOPIC_?"

I suspect those are not your actual topic strings though.

**Further Reading**

[IBM MQ Wildcard Schemes](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q005010_.htm)